# Pine Script - Multicolor line for up and down trend

Tags: pine-script

The below code display single color line for uptrend and downtrend. Also there is a connecting line between the uptrend and downtrend. Can someone help me get 2 color lines and remove the connecting line between uptrend and downtrend. More details can be found in the screenshot.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqeze.jpg)

```
//@version=4
study(title="Trend Line", shorttitle="Trend Line", overlay=true, resolution="")
length = input(20,"Entry Length", minval=1)
len2=input(10, "Exit Length", minval=1)        

lower = lowest(length)
upper = highest(length)

up=highest(high,length)
down=lowest(low,length)
K1=barssince(high>=up[1])<=barssince(low<=down[1]) ? down : up
plot(K1, title="Trend Line", color=color.red, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a result like this

```
//@version=4
study(title="Trend Line", shorttitle="Trend Line", overlay=true, resolution="")
length = input(20,"Entry Length", minval=1)
len2 = input(10, "Exit Length", minval=1)        

lower = lowest(length)
upper = highest(length)

up = highest(high,length)
down = lowest(low,length)

K1 = barssince(high >= up[1])<=barssince(low <= down[1]) ? down : up

linecolor = (open > K1) and (open[1] > K1[1]) ? color.red : (open < K1) and (open[1] <     K1[1]) ? color.green : na

plot(K1, title="Trend Line", style = plot.style_linebr, color=linecolor, linewidth=2)
```